# jquery modal window loading in frames

Tags: jquery

I am loading a modal window via:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/myFile.cfm?cmid=<cfoutput>#someid#</cfoutput>",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function (h) {
          $("div#salesNotes", window.parent.document).html(h);
      }
 });
```

Inside myFile.cfm, I have bunch of jquery syntax controlling button clicks and such. When I load this file directly into browser, everything works fine. No errors. When I load this file as mentioned above, none of these controlls work. I tried attaching load() and putting all the functions in there, but that didn't work either. When I try to alert a button id, I get undefined. What to do?

Comment: What does `/myFile.cfm` return? Is it the whole markup including `html` tags?

Comment: It wasn't surrounded by html tags. I changed it to include html tags but still no luck. It doesn't throw any errors. They simply don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. all the controls have to be in the following format:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/myFile.cfm?cmid=<cfoutput>#someid#</cfoutput>",
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (h) {
      $("div#salesNotes", window.parent.document).html(h);
        $("#myButton", window.parent.document).click(function(){ ... });
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the code is not running then it has to do with how the data is being put on the page.

Browsers generally don't run code that's simply pasted onto the page, I generally hate eval but the easiest way is to get raw JS code and eval it when it gets to the page.

```
  success: function (h) {
      eval(h);
  }
```

If the external content coming in is a mix of html and javascript, you're better off using write instead:

```
document.write(h);
```

Also make sure to check that the code inside is a.ctually executing the event methods correctly.